# Constructing a custom measure for 'trust'

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, measure-theory

I need some inspiration for a measure that transforms a distribution of dimensionless 'priority values' $x = \{x_i\}$ to a real $t \in [0,1]$, which we'll call the (dimensionless) 'trust'.

A priority value $x_i$ can lie anywhere on the real axis with an expectation value of zero, but since the $x_i$'s are already scaled the majority of them will probably lie within, say, $[-3, 3]$.

A positive priority value should increase the trust, and vice versa for negative priority values. If the mass of $x$ is positive (negative), this means the user has (not) been given predominantly priority and the user's trust $t$ should be biased to 1 (0), with $t = 1/2$ representing a neutral trust of the user towards the service giving her priority.

In addition, a clustering of priority values means that the priority is given consistently, and should also increase or decrease the trust depending on the sign of the $x_i$'s. A very dense distribution $x$, all $x_i > 0$, that lies far from zero should produce $t \to 1$. Likewise, the same distribution of negative values should make $t$ tend to $0$. If the $x_i$ were discrete values, the normalized entropy of $x$ would be a good choice for penalizing non-local $x_i$'s, but that can't be used here.

If $x$ is located quasi-symmetrically around 0, then $t$ should be around $1/2$.

I had in my mind
$$ t = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\sum x_i}{\sum |x_i|} + 1 \right),$$
but this doesn't penalize clustered values, and is unstable. For example, small positive values of $x_i$ would produce $t = 1$, while $t \approx 1/2$ is desired. I also thought of normalized skew measures (Bowley skewness etc.) but they seem clumsy when the number of $x_i$'s is small, and they measure skewness wrt. the mean value, while $t$ should compare $x$ with zero. The number of $x_i$'s may not be large enough to have $E(x) \approx 0$.

I would appreciate any idea and thank you all for your time!

Comment: This seems very ill-constrained based on your description, so not too clear what you are after. Off the top of my head, perhaps applying the [logistic function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/logistic/info) to your sample mean would work? (i.e. $t=1/(1+e^{-\bar{x}})$)

Comment: @GeoMatt22: actually, that's already a very good suggestion. $t = 1/(1+\exp{-\bar{x}/\sigma_x})$ has all the properties, only the case of a sharp distribution around zero will need further investigation. Thanks!

Comment: @GeoMatt22: I decided to go with it, so if you want to post it as an aswer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are after, as the description is under-constrained.

However the [logistic function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/logistic/info)
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$
maps $x=\big[-\!\infty,0,+\infty\big]$ to $f(x)=\big[\,0,\tfrac{1}{2},1\,\big]$.

So perhaps applying this to your sample mean could work, i.e. $t=f[\bar{x}]$.